# rbenv on OS X Mavericks not work

Tags: osx-mavericks, rbenv

I try to change my ruby version and I get this on my terminal :

```
Cristians-MacBook-Air% rbenv versions
  system
  1.9.3-p448
  2.0.0-p247
* 2.1.0 (set by /Users/Cristian/.ruby-version)
Cristians-MacBook-Air% ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

rbenv say  2.1.0 is active but then I run `ruby -v` my active ruby version is other 2.1.0p0

In my `.bash_profile` :

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH='brew --prefix rbenv'/shims:'brew --prefix rbenv'/bin:$PATH
```

I am not using ZSH yet.

Some idea??..
Thanks!!

Comment: Aren't `2.1.0` and `2.1.0p0` the same thing, in this case?

Comment: Hi @summea, I think no, because ruby 2.1.0 corresponds to rbenv and ruby 2.1.0p0 corresponds to RVM.. I need RVM to work momentarily while fix rbenv problem.

Comment: Wait, you're using both rvm and rbenv at the same time?

Comment: It's not fine, i know.. But I have 2 days trying to solve this problem and don't have more time to spend in my search.. I need to continue working in my project while continue in search for a solution.. This is why RVM is installed in my computer.

Comment: I have worked with Mac OS X and rbenv for the last two years and only with Mavericks have found this problem..

Comment: What's the output of `which ruby`?

Comment: Hi @mipadi, I think the problem is solved. I got a new Macbook and it works fine now. should I delete the question?